# JSF index.xhtml and redirect to faces action

Tags: jsf, redirect, jsf-2, myfaces

I think its a good practice to have an index page (in my case index.xhtml).
I want to pass some action on index page (for example in struts:`<c:redirect url="list.do" />` and I go to struts action class without any links and buttons) I know if I want to use navigation I should use commandLink-s or buttons). I can write `<h:commandButton>` with onclick javascript function, but I don't feel this is the best option.

I'm totally new to JSF (using JSF 2.0) and I need your advice. What are the best practices for redirecting from index page to an action in controller?

///new version

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<f:view>
<ui:insert name="metadata"/>
    <f:viewParam name="action" value="listItems.xtml"/>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{yourBean.methodInManagedBean}" />
<h:body></h:body>
</f:view>
</html>

public class ForwardBean {

    private String action;

    // getter, setter

    public void navigate(PhaseEvent event) {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        String outcome = action; 
        facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(facesContext, null, outcome);
    }
}
```

Comment: so is it working after the modification?

Comment: why do u need <f:viewParam> for this?

Comment: just remove "list.do" part in my solution and add your url "listItems.xtml" and use the method which i have given, which is public void methodInManagedBean() which is pointed from <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{yourBean.methodInManagedBean}" />

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use JSF `preRenderView` event to redirect to another page in following manner,

***In your index.xhtml file***

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<f:view>
<ui:insert name="metadata"/>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{yourBean.methodInManagedBean}" />
<h:body></h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

In managed bean,
***1st way is***

```
    public class yourClass{

    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ConfigurableNavigationHandler nav = (ConfigurableNavigationHandler)fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();

    public void methodInManagedBean() throws IOException {
        nav.performNavigation("list.do");//add your URL here, instead of list.do
    }
    }
```

or you can use ***2nd way***

```
    public class yourClass{ 

    public void methodInManagedBean() throws IOException {
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("list.do");//add your URL here, instead of list.do
    }
    }
```